# Why author has not specified what actually happens when $n\to \infty$ for the sequence $P_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

In my book the author is giving the rigorous definition of integrals and here is what he writes:

> Let $f: [a,b] \mapsto \mathbb R $ be a bounded function. Then $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ if and only if there is a sequence $\{P_n\}$ of partitions of the interval $[a,b]$ such that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left[ U(f, P_n) - L(f,P_n)\right] =0$$.

But what I don’t understand is that the author doesn’t ever say that as $n$ gets larger and larger $P_n$ gets finer and finer. If he doesn’t define how $P_n$ depends on $n$ then what’s the meaning of defining something like
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left[
         U(f,P_n) -L(f,P_n) \right]
$$
From what I think he should say that $n$ suggests the number of points in the partition $P_n$, because then it would be easier to see why upper and lower sum will converge (upper sum will decrease, lower sum will increase).

But when I asked it to someone, they replied that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} [U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n)]$$ is perfectly fine and they used the concept of limit point/accumulation point to explain that it’s valid, but I couldn’t convince myself with that.

Please express yourself about how you think about it.

Comment: Your partition can be as coarse as you want if say $f(x) \equiv 1$, in which case $P_n = [a,b]$ for all $n$. It need not get finer as $n$ gets larger, you just need such a sequence to exist.

Comment: @Dayton I’m really unable to understand what does “you just need such a sequence to exist” mean? In what cases partitions wouldn’t exist?

Comment: You need a sequence $\{P_n\}$ to exist such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}[U(f,P_n) - L(f,P_n)] =0$. As an example $f(x) = 0$ for $x$ rational and $f(x) = 1$ for $x$ irrational on $[0,1]$, you cannot find a sequence $\{P_n\}$ which gives the limit of zero since $L(f,P_n) = 0$ and $U(f,P_n) = 1$ for any partition. Therefore, this function $f$ is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: @Dayton What does $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ signify then?

Comment: You define a nested sequence $\{P_n\}$ in advance such that each partition $P_n$ in the sequence $\{P_n\}$ consists of a finite collections of intervals whose union is $[a,b]$. Therefore for each $P_n$, both $U(f, P_n)$ and $L(f, P_n)$ are simply real numbers. So $\{U(f,P_n) - L(f, P_n)\}$ is just a sequence of real numbers, for which you can compute a limit. In fact (if $f$ is bounded), the sequence $\{U(f,P_n) - L(f, P_n)\}$ is a decreasing, bounded sequence of real numbers so the limit exists. The definition just requires you to find a sequence $\{P_n\}$ for which this limit is zero.

Comment: You can avoid sequences by using inf and sup. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral. I think it is clearer.

Comment: @Dayton  The sequence of partitions doesn't have to be nested; the definition is OK as stated, allowing any sequence of partitions.

Comment: The author wouldn't have had to mention "limit" or "sequence". All he's really saying is that, for any $\varepsilon\gt0$, there is a partition $P$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)\lt\varepsilon$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass No, I agree, they do not have to be nested. But you can assume it is nested without any loss of generality. If you have a sequence of partitions $\{P_n\}$, then the sequence $\{P'_n\}$ with $P_n' := \cup_{i=1}^n P_i$ is strictly finer and is nested. This is convenient to make $\{U(f,P_n) - L(f,P_n)\}$ monotonic and thus guaranteeing the existence of the limit to a real number.

Comment: We can always state and prove theorems about sequences without specifying the dependence on $n$ explicitly. For example, the statement "for every real $L$ there is a sequence $l_n$ of rational numbers such that $l_n\to L$" holds and we don't need to know the exact dependence of $l_n$ on $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really doesn't matter if $\{P_n\}$ becomes finer or contains more points as $n$ increases. Indeed, let $\mathcal{P}$ denote the set of all partitions of $[a, b]$ and consider two sets

\begin{align*}
A &= \{ L(f, P) : P \in \mathcal{P} \}, &
B &= \{ U(f, P) : P \in \mathcal{P} \}.
\end{align*}

Then we have the following observations:

1. The inequality $\sup A \leq \inf B$ always holds.
2. $f$ is Darboux integrable if and only if $\sup A = \inf B$. (This is often taken as the definition of integrability.)
3. By the property of supremum/infimum, there exist sequences $\{ P_n \}$ and $\{ Q_n \}$ in $\mathcal{P}$ such that
   $$\lim_{n\to\infty} L(f, P_n) = \sup A \qquad\text{and}\qquad \lim_{n\to\infty} U(f, Q_n) = \inf B. $$
   For instance, for each integer $n \geq 1$, pick $P_n, Q_n \in \mathcal{P}$ such that $L(f, P_n) \geq \sup A - \frac{1}{n}$ and $U(f, Q_n) \leq \inf B + \frac{1}{n}$. Also, note that we do not impose any specific conditions on $\{P_n\}$ and $\{Q_n\}$ here.

The definition is then based on the observation that $\{ P_n \}$ and $\{ Q_n \}$ may be chosen so as to satisfy $P_n = Q_n$ for all $n \geq 1$.

To conclude, we mention that the followings are equivalent:

1. $\sup_{P \in \mathcal{P}} L(f,P) = \inf_{P \in \mathcal{P}} U(f, P)$.
2. There exist partitions $\{P_n\}$ and $\{Q_n\}$ such that $U(f, Q_n) - L(f, P_n) \to 0$.
3. There exist partitions $\{P_n\}$ such that $U(f, P_n) - L(f, P_n) \to 0$.
4. There exist partitions $\{P_n\}$ such that $P_n \subseteq P_{n+1}$ for all $n$ and $U(f, P_n) - L(f, P_n) \to 0$.
5. There exist partitions $\{P_n\}$ such that $\| P_n \| \to 0$ and $U(f, P_n) - L(f, P_n) \to 0$.

Here, $\| \{ a = x_0 < x_1 < \dots < x_{n-1} < x_n = b\} \| := \max_{1\leq i \leq n} |x_i - x_{i-1}|$ denotes the mesh size of a partition.

Comment: For the point mentioned at the end we just need to use $R_n=P_n\cup Q_n$ and then we will have $L(f, R_n) \to \sup A, U(f, R_n) =\inf B$.

Comment: Okay, I have understood that $$ \left[ U(f,P_n) -L(f,P_n) \right]$$ is itself a sequence. And we say that this sequence **eventually** converge to zero. Is that right @ParamanandSingh ?

Comment: @Knight, A sequence of real numbers may be either eventually zero (i.e., its terms are identically zero for all sufficiently large indices) or converges to zero, and they are different. What do you mean when you say a sequence *eventually converges* to zero?

Comment: @Knight: Well there is no need of _eventually_ here. If a sequence converges to $0$ then it simply converges to $0$. I don't see your thought process behind emphasizing this statement by adding _eventually_. Can you elaborate more what you had in your mind?

Comment: Sangchul Lee, @ParamanandSingh Let me ask a very obvious question, we have a sequence $\{P_n\}$ okay? Then how $P_1, P_2, P_3....$ Are different from each other? What is happening to $P$ as its index is increasing?

Comment: “Eventually converges to zero” means it is not zero in the beginning but after some time it keeps on getting closer and closer to zero.

Comment: @Knight: a sequence $P$ is just a function like $P:\mathbb{N} \to X$ and the image $P(n) $ is usually written as $P_n$. Thus if we are dealing with real sequences (ie $X=\mathbb{R} $) then $P_1,P_2,\dots$ are real numbers and there is nothing more to it unless we are given more information about the sequence $P_n$.

Comment: @Knight: if that's your thought behind _eventually_ then there is no need to add this word. The term _converge_ to zero means the same but with more precision and without ambiguity.

Comment: @Knight, For a general function $f$, the sequence $\{P_n\}$ in the definition in OP will have a tendency of containing larger number of points, but this is not a necessaity. In an extreme case, if $f$ is a constant function, then we can actually choose $P_n = \{a, b\}$ identically for all $n$. And if $f$ is continuous, we can choose $P_n = \{a + (b-a)\frac{k}{n} : k = 0, 1, \dots, n\}$, which contains larger number of points as $n$ increase, but is not nested in the sense that $P_n \not\subseteq P_{n+1}$ for all $n \geq 2$.

Comment: Why not to say $\lim_{n\to \infty} P_n$ means “number of points is increasing in the partition” ?

Comment: @SangchulLee Okay, so when we write $$\lim_{n\to 0} [ U(f,P_n )- L(f,P_n)]=0$$ we mean that the sequence is approaching to zero, but the question is “what is making that sequence to converge to zero”?

Comment: @Knight, Indeed, that expression literally means that the sequence $\{ U(f,P_n) - L(f,P_n) : n \geq 1 \}$ of real numbers converges to zero as $n\to\infty$. And again, the definition of Darboux integrability in OP's version is stated as: $$\text{$f$ is Darboux integrable if we can find a sequence of partitions $\{P_n\}$ s.t.}\\ \lim_{n\to\infty} (U(f,P_n) - L(f,P_n)) = 0$$ It never claims that any function would satisfy such a property nor that any sequence of partitions $\{P_n\}$ would work even if $f$ is integrable.

Comment: I agree. Thank you Sangchul and @ParamanandSingh